# Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in

Tags: php, fatal-error

New here so please forgive me if I’m incorrect in my posting. I am having this issue:

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in
>   /home/content/c/a/l/calchrome/html/gallery/php/includes/php/libmanager.php
>   on line 1363

I can't find the syntax error here; usually it's pretty obvious with something like this, but I cannot figure this one out.  It's not the usual `$this->$var` type error.

```
   foreach($cfg['social_plugin'] as $plugin=>$value)
    {
        $social_order[$this->$value['order']] = $plugin;
    }

    ksort($social_order);

    for($a=1;$a<sizeof($social_order)+1;$a++)

  **this is the section with the problem** 
    {
        $obj = $cfg['social_plugin'][$social_order[$a]];
        $list.='<li id="'.$obj['order'].'_'.($a+1).'"><label for="'.$obj['link'].'"><img src="includes/images/'.$obj['image'].'" /> '.$obj['display'].'</label><input name="'.$social_order[$a].'_L" type="text" id="'.$social_order[$a].'_L" value="'.$this->$obj['link'].'" class="sg_form_long"/></li>';     
    }**

    $html.='<div class="sg_setting_box" id="sortable1">
    <h3>- Soical Information -
    <br/><span>Dragging each plugin can re-arrange the order shown in front end</span>
    </h3>


    <ul class="sg_social">'.$list.'</ul>

    </div>';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help get better answers, what language is your program in?  It looks like [tag:perl]; if so, please add that to the tags, to help Perl experts find it.

Comment: sorry this is part of a module and im not quite sure beyond php

Comment: Hope my edit helps.  Minor nitpick: "Cannot access empty property" is a runtime error (unexpected state) rather than a syntax error (not following the rules of the language).  A bit like the difference between an untrue sentence and a spelling error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$this->$obj['link']
```

to

```
$obj['link']
```

`$this->` is for the current class property

Answer (score 0):

You should change (if obj is defined in your class as a property)
From

```
$this->$obj['link']
```

to

```
$this->obj['link']
```

OR (if obj is only define as a local variable)

to
    $obj['link']

Just as the answer above suggested